# Proof request: every polytope has a facet

Tags: discrete-mathematics, convex-geometry, polyhedra, polytopes, discrete-geometry

When I was reading Ziegler's book "Lectures on Polytopes" this statement appeared to be never proven formally.

> **Question:** does every (convex, bounded, non-empty) polytope have a facet?

Here I assume that the polytope $P\subset\Bbb R^d$ has dimensions $d$, and a facet is a face of dimension $d-1$.

Depending on the amount of theory developed to this point there are many ways to prove this. But it seems some element in the chain towards such a proof it missing in the book. E.g, proving any of the following statements might already be sufficient:

- the face lattice is graded of length $d+1$ (stated but never proven in Ziegler)
- the face lattice is co-atomic (proven using duality and the next unproven fact)
- given a $\delta$-face $f$ of $P$, its dual face in $P^\circ$ is of dimension $d-1-\delta$ (not proven as far as I can tell)

Maybe I am just overlooking the proof in the book, but an elementary self-contained proof of the existence of a facet is welcome anyway.

Comment: Depending on the "existence" of the nullitope (wrt. your definition of "polytope", i.e. in case the single polytope of dimension -1) either every point (polytope of dimension 0) has no facet, or at least that nullitope itself has no facet! - Thence you'll need at least some assumption of d>0 or the like.

Comment: @DrRichard I consider the empty set as a convex polytope and hence as a facet of ever point. I also state the question only for non-empty polytopes.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the amount of convex geometry and topology available at this point, the following would be a possible reasoning.

If $P$ is full-dimensional, then every $x\in\partial P$ is contained in some proper face of $P$. This follows from the [existence of a supporting hyperplane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supporting_hyperplane#Supporting_hyperplane_theorem) at $x$, whose intersection with $P$ is a face.

If we assume that $P$ has no facet, then $\partial P$ is the union of convex sets of dimension $\le d-2$. But the boundary of a $d$-dimensional compact convex set is homeomorphic to the $(d-1)$-sphere, which cannot be embedded in such a union.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Ziegler's book and will be using Grunbaum as a reference. That is, I define a face of a convex set to be its intersection with a supporting hyperplane, and a facet to be a maximal proper face.

Let us prove that every polyhedron $P$ has a facet. Let $\mathcal{H}:=\{H_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be an irredundant family of hyperplanes such that $P:=\cap_{i=1}^nH_i^+$, where $H_i^+$ is the positive closed half-space defined by $H_i$. Then every $H_i$ is a supporting hyperplane for $P$. By definition, $P\cap H_1$ is a face of $P$. Additionally, since $\mathcal{H}$ is irredundant, $P\cap H_1$ has codimension $1$, i.e. $aff(P\cap H_1)=H_1$.

Let $P\cap H$ be another proper face of $P$. Suppose that $P\cap H_1\subseteq P\cap H$. Then, $$P\cap H_1\subseteq H\Rightarrow aff(P\cap H_1)\subseteq H\Rightarrow H_1\subseteq H\Rightarrow H_1=H\Rightarrow P\cap H_1=P\cap H.$$ Therefore, $P\cap H_1$ is a facet.

Comment: Most relevant to my situation (a facet is a face of codimension 1) is your following claim: since $\mathcal H$ is irredundant $P\cap H_1$ has codimension 1. How can I see this?

Comment: The set $P\cap H_1\cap (\cup_{i=2}^nH_i)$ is closed. Since $\mathcal{H}$ is irredundant, $S:=(P\cap H_1)\setminus \cup_{i=2}^nH_i\neq \emptyset$, and $S$ is also open (in the relative topology of $H_1$). The affine hull of a nonempty open subset of a linear space is the whole space.

Comment: I can follow every step except for the following: why do we have $S\not=\emptyset$ when $\mathcal H$ is irredundant?